# Unable to autoload constant Role,expected role.rb to define it issue in rails cancan role based authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I'm developing a rails app with role based user authorization with the help of cancan documentation.
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization
I want 3 user levels as Admin ,Manager,Customer in my rails application. So i've created a devise model as Users and added a migration to add the user role to it.So when a user is signed up it stores the users role(whether he is an admin,a manager or a customer). And in my application there are models and controllers for product,delivery,services. And I want to set access levels to each models.

So Admin have access to all models, controllers

Manager have access to Product, Delivery

Customer have access to Services

And i've written the Ability model as follows

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.roles == "admin"
      can :manage , :all
    elsif user.roles == "manager"
      can :read, Products, Delivery
    elsif user.roles == "customer"
      can :read, Services
    end
end
end
```

And in my product's show view i've the following code

```
<% if can? :manage ,@products%>

<h1>Products</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<p>     <%= product.name%>
<p>         <%= product.price %><br>
<p>    <%= product.qty %><br>

  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

User model is as follows

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

         ROLES = %i[admin manager customer]

end
```

Role Model

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

end
```

When trying to access the product controllers show view i'm getting the following error.

```
LoadError in ProductsController#show
Unable to autoload constant Role, expected /Users/tharindu/MyTasks/try2/mynewtask/app/models/role.rb to define it

Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

       if user.role == "admin"
         can :manage, :all, @products
       elsif user.role == "manager"
         can :read, Products, Delivery,Accounts
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Your `Role` model says: `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` where is the `Role` class?

Comment: that must be the issue.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are trying to implement doesn't has a seperate `Role` model and you are adding an association `belongs_to :role`. Instead you are saving the `role` in `User` table itself. So remove the association defined which should fix the issue.

And currently the `User` would have one `role` you can also assign multiple roles to him as mentioned in the tutorial using a `bitmask`.

But using any of the two methods you are not creating a seperate model so the association can't be defined instead you need to create instance methods. For seperate `Role` model refer this: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model

Answer (score 1):

Your role model doesn't define a role class. Change

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

to

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
```